# The word/phrase for the person who makes all the profit while others are suffering?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

> "I hate this war."
>   
> "Me too. It's bad for everyone"
>   
> "But you know who is profiting from this - the coffin seller."

How do I define that coffin seller in one or more words?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe the word you are looking for is [*profiteer*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/profiteer) which meriam-webster online defines as

> ## [profiteer](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/profiteer)
>
> ### *noun* prof·i·teer \ˌprä-fə-ˈtir\
>
> :  one who makes what is considered an unreasonable profit especially on the sale of essential goods during times of emergency

Comment: Profiteer implies *unreasonable* profit from an *inflated* sale. Coffin sellers benefit from war even at usual sale price and they don't do malicious sales or directly instigate a war for the purpose of increased demand.

Answer (score 1):

"Profiteer" is perfect to answer to the question in the title.

In the context of the example, i.e. "coffin seller", the words **bloodsuckers** (*or leeches*) and **scavenger** (or *vulture*) may fit, if you want to be more literary.

Answer (score 1):

I believe in this instance the word you need is Vulture. Vultures are found in nature feeding upon the dead and dying and thus gaining life at the expense of others.
If you wish to convey someone who feeds upon the living at their expense a closer match would be Vampire. 
Both of these words have been used to refer to people who profit from the suffering of others.

Answer (score -4):

I PROPOSE THE INVENTION OF A NEW TERM FOR THIS DEFINITION: n. SHKRELIST  (REFERENCE: MARTIN SHKRELI, CEO OF TURIN PHARMACEUTICALS)  V. TO SHKREL

Comment: PLEASE DON’T SHOUT! We're right here, we can hear you.